# teamviewer window is suddenly very skinny

Tags: macos, teamviewer

I must have hit a strange key combination and my full screen team viewer window is suddenly very skinny (approximately one third of original size).

Does anyone know what I did by chance?

It has something to do with zoom.

Do not know how to undo it

---

I don't know exactly which key it is but <kbd>Apple</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Apple</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Apple</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> makes the window full screen and perfect. This is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this Team Viewer window very skinny issue, you can try by increasing the screen resolution.

You can set the screen resolution by going through the menu "View -> Screen Resolution" from your Team Viewer window.

For eg: Set the screen resolution as "1366 X 768".